# How to properly make and sign http request to query AWS cloudwatch metrics using JSON payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to make my own HTTP request to query cloudwatch metrics from AWS API. The reason is because I need to define my query in JSON format (similar to how `aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --cli-input-json <json_file_name>` works). And according to [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html), this should be possible. However, I'm having some trouble properly making and signing my HTTP request. With the following code, I'm getting `{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException"}` error. And there is little information in the response to help me troubleshoot. Am I signing my request wrong? Or am I missing some parameters/headers?

```
        String query = "{\n" +
                "  \"StartTime\": 1628589600,\n" +
                "  \"EndTime\": 1628590200,\n" +
                "  \"MetricDataQueries\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"Id\": \"mymetric1\",\n" +
                "      \"Label\": \"counter\",\n" +
                "      \"MetricStat\": {\n" +
                "        \"Metric\": {\n" +
                "          \"Namespace\": \"AWS/EC2\",\n" +
                "          \"MetricName\": \"CPUUtilization\",\n" +
                "          \"Dimensions\": [\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "              \"Name\": \"InstanceId\",\n" +
                "              \"Value\": \"my_instance_id\"\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "          ]\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        \"Period\": 60,\n" +
                "        \"Stat\": \"Average\",\n" +
                "        \"Unit\": \"Percent\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder()
                .profileName("my_profile").build();

        Aws4PresignerParams params = Aws4PresignerParams.builder()
                .doubleUrlEncode(true)
                .awsCredentials(credProvider.resolveCredentials())
                .signingName("monitoring")
                .signingRegion(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .timeOffset(0)
                .build();

        SdkHttpFullRequest requestToSign = SdkHttpFullRequest.builder()
                .method(SdkHttpMethod.POST)
                .protocol("https")
                .host("monitoring.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
                .appendRawQueryParameter("Action", "GetMetricData")
                .appendRawQueryParameter("Version", "2010-08-01")
                .appendRawQueryParameter("StartTime", "1628589600")
                .appendRawQueryParameter("EndTime", "1628590200")
                .appendRawQueryParameter("MetricDataQueries.member.N", "1")
                .contentStreamProvider(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream(query.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                .build();

        SdkHttpFullRequest signedRequest = AwsS3V4Signer.create().presign(requestToSign, params);
        URL url = signedRequest.getUri().toURL();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(query.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), MediaType.parse("application/x-amz-json-1.0"));
        Request r = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(r).execute()) {
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        }
```

Comment: Why not use AWS SDK?

Comment: @Marcin Because unlike Stackdriver sdk, AWS SDK doesn't support passing the metrics query in JSON format, which is required in my case.